# Displaying a .txt file in my html using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to display my log.txt in my log.html.
For some reason my page is completely blank.
And I dont get to see anything from my file.
Code:

```
def log():
    with open("logs.txt", "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
    return render_template('log.html', content=content)
```

HTML LOG TEMPLATE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/nav.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/basiclayout.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>


</style>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('hello_world') }}" >Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('notepad') }}">Notepad</a></li>
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('explorer') }}">Explorer </a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('log') }}">Log </a></li>
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('upload') }}">Upload </a></li>
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('uploads') }}">Uploads </a></li>
    <li ><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>



</ul>
<div class="alert">
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
       {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
        </div>

    <pre>{{ content }}</pre>


</body>
</html>
```

Added my HTML Template now.

Comment: what does **better** mean?

Comment: please post your complete template of "log.html" since there is no way it can just be what you show here and result in the screenshot you added as a comment on my answer...

Comment: There you go Joran.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 return Response(content, mimetype='text/plain')
```

but really you probably want to use something like logstash...

Comment: what if I still want to return my log.html template and in that I want to display the log?
Otherwise I could easily `return send_from_directory(......)`

Comment: then i dont understand your question clearly... a better way would not be having a template that just does `<pre>{}</pre>` ... `send_from_directory` would also be a better way imho ... but  this is more explicit ..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cyuuw9 hope that helps you, to understand my question clearly =)

Comment: so the template you showed is not really the template you are using? or you are loading that into a div with ajax? I think you are missing some critical details in your original question

Comment: I've put that `<pre>{{ content }}</pre>`in my log.html which is my template. Sorry I'm still a beginner so.. haha.

Comment: where does the menu come from ... you are not showing us enough detail at this time.... pre should work fine...

Comment: I've edited my post and put the Source Code of the template in there.

Comment: ok good job ... and now my aswer is not really ... if you want all that menu stuff thats a-ok way to do it... (although its probably better to look into how inheritance works in templates) if its not working at all that indicates the logfile is empty (often this is a case where the os is not flushing the file as frequently as it should)

Comment: The log file is definitely not empty haha. It's not a real log file. Its just a random .txt I've created, with log entries from my server. I want to test it locally so that I know how it's done on the server. (If you know what I mean). Back to my actual problem: How do I display any text inside a .txt file on my log.html :)

Comment: Well this is awkward. It's working now with my original code. The .txt was indeed empty. I apologize for that and Thank you for your help and your time =)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be better if for the `log` to read the file `backwards` in order to access the `last log first`.

```
pip3 install file-read-backwards
```

For example, I will show this code backwards:

> In your case, it is necessary to replace `app.py` with `logs.txt`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

with FileReadBackwards("app.py") as f:
    # getting lines by lines starting from the last line up
    b_lines = [ row for row in f ]

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', b_lines=b_lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### UPDATE - without libraries

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    b_lines = [row for row in reversed(list(open("app.py")))]
    return render_template('index.html', b_lines=b_lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Put in your `log.html`:

```html
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;Description:
<br>
<textarea id="stackoverflow" name="stackoverflow_review" rows="35" cols="55">   
   {% for line in b_lines %}
      {{ line }}
   {% endfor %}
</textarea>
```

output:

[image]

> In your case, the latest changes from the `logs.txt` file will be displayed first.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
But whenever file is changed, I need to restart flask. Do you have solution for this?

Comment: @Mhd Ridho Swasta: If you helped, he always show you that by clicking on a useful answer. As for the second part, I didn't understand it the best, but there will be no changes if you change the debug with `app.run(debug=False)`.

Answer (score -1):

There are two files one being "file.py" and the respective HTML file being invoked from the templates folder.

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="/root/templates")
def search():
with open("test","r") as file:
     content = file.readlines()
     print(content)

return render_template("file2.html", content = content)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

2. File2.html:

   Not sure how to attach HTML file. attaching a screen shot . Please refer[image]

Comment: You can copy/paste the html into a code box, saves people having to retype